# Use Different Font for Different Elements in Sublime Text 2

Tags: sublimetext2

I'm loving [Source Code Pro](http://blogs.adobe.com/typblography/2012/09/source-code-pro.html) as a font. However, it can't be put in italics easily for Sublime Text 2 in-code comments.

Is there a way to set a different font for comments in Sublime Text 2?

Comment: Post-dates the question, but Source Code Pro has had [italics since 2015](https://blog.typekit.com/2015/07/17/source-code-pro-italic-greek-cyrillic/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Sublime Text 3](http://www.sublimetext.com/3) (now in beta) produces a "synthetic" italic:

[image: Example of synthetic italic]

Comment: Interesting. That is exactly what I want. How stable would you say ST3 is? Would you recommend it for a professional work environment?

Comment: @ChrisRedford I've just installed it recently so I can't really say. However it's been in beta for a while, and others do seem to be using it successfully. Note that not all plugins are compatible.

Comment: Okay. Well, in time, I'm guessing this will be the best answer, in any case.

Comment: Hi did you find a solution yet the author of this video for instance uses a different font for the comments https://laracasts.com/series/whats-new-in-laravel-5-3/episodes/13

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can select a font just for comments. I'm a little confused by the staetement "it can't be put in italics easily". I would think all you would have to do is look for the comment scope in the color scheme file and replace it with something like...

```
<dict>
    <key>name</key>
    <string>Comment</string>
    <key>scope</key>
    <string>comment</string>
    <key>settings</key>
    <dict>
        <key>fontStyle</key>
        <string>italic</string>
        <key>foreground</key>
        <string>#75715E</string>
    </dict>
</dict>
```

Note the above is based on the `Monokai.tmTheme`. Of course, you could have tried this already and perhaps there is some weird font thing. If so, ignore this post :)

Comment: Right. Well, I say "it can't be put in italics easily" because when I use it in a word processor (Pages), I cannot make it italic. Yet, somehow Textmate is able to make the font italic for its theme using it. I think Textmate makes fonts italic algorithmically, even if they don't have an "actual" italic version.

Comment: Ah I see, you can trying asking on the ST forums. Perhaps someone there would have more insight into the issue. No guarantees though.

Comment: I had the same issue with Source Code Pro. I recently discovered [Cousine](http://www.google.com/fonts#UsePlace:use/Collection:Cousine) and now use it in TextMate on OSX and Sublime Text (2 and 3) on OSX and Linux. For some reason it doesn't display `;` properly on Windows XP (my machine at work, don't have admin access), so I use Lucida Sans Typewriter with Sublime here.